# Prolog: Understanding logic flow

Tags: prolog

I was reading [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online) and I'm confused about their use of logic and I was hoping someone can clarify the ambiguity of arguments in rules.

For example, on [Chapter 1, knowledge base 4](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse1) they reference the following rule:

`loves(vincent,mia).`

They then provide a query:

`loves(marsellus,X),  woman(X).`

and then the make the English statement:

*"Now, remember that `,` means "and", so this query says: is there any individual X such that **Marsellus loves X** and X is a woman ?"*

The key word being, `Marsellus loves X`.

This is worded in a way that makes me think there is some "**logic**" tied to the arrangement of arguments, such as to say,

Is it true that `loves(vincent,mia).` "**logically**" means:

1. vincent loves mia?

**BUT** is it false that

2. mia loves vincent?

That's what I originally thought but then on [Chapter 3, example 2: Descendant](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse9) they have the following example of:

`child(bridget,caroline).`

Then the English statement: "That is, **Caroline is a child of Bridget**"

But if #1 above is true (vincent loves mia), then shouldn't this be read as Bridget is a child of Caroline?

Or does the order of arguments not matter and it's your additional programming that will determine the logic of the arguments?

Comment: A predicate `r(a,b)` means that (a,b) is in the relation r:A->B. 
Nothing more is implied. So everything depends on how you define the relation r.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loves(X, Y)` intuitively would mean `X` loves `Y` but not `Y` loves `X`. But as a programmer, you could assume it's symmetrical. It just wouldn't be as intuitive. It just depends upon how you choose to define it. Prolog Now chose the most intuitive meaning, so `loves(X, Y)` means `X` loves `Y`, but not `Y` loves `X`.

Whether `child(X, Y)` means `X` is a child of `Y` or `Y` is a child of `X` is up to the programmer. `child` used by itself as the name of the fact/predicate in this context is a bit ambiguous here (it's not a verb and isn't part of a phrase) and you just have to roll with whatever the Prolog Now site chose as their meaning. When you view the functor as a verb, the arguments are interpreted left to right as expected. So, better, would be to use `child_of(X, Y)` to mean `X` is a child of `Y` so that it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Prolog as a language wouldn't care whether you define `love(X,Y)` as X loves Y or Y loves X. It's probably just a convention that we tend to follow in first order logic. 
As to why we'd choose the ordering convention we usually follow, It's probably because the predicate defines a relation between two terms. So the order would depend on how you define the relation.

A predicate `r(a,b)` means that (a,b) is in the relation r:A->B.

The way i would clear my doubts of the case you've given in the question is:

`loves(a,?)` ? should anything which a loves. And 
`child(a,?)` ? should be anything which is a child of a.

It would depend on how you define the relation 'child'.

As far as i know ( which isn't far ), There's no hard rule in logic that stops you from defining predicates the way you want. You could define `love(X,Y)` as 'X loves Y' or 'X is loved by Y' as long as you're consistent.

Comment: well, there's an actual convention described in books, that p(X,Y) should really mean 'X p Y', if possible. and `r:A->B` is more of a notation for functions, not relations. :)